# Bootstrap3: Row of tabs or links - when screen narrows, excess tabs should flow into the rightmost dropdown tab

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

The scenario:

On a big screen, the horizontal row holds 6-7 tabs without issues. But as the screen begins to narrow, the right-most tab should become (or such a tab be added) a dropdown tab with a "More" label and receive the other tabs as they start to lack space to be displayed.

The process of switching to the mobile view should end with only the first and second tabs (an example) displayed as usual, plus with the abovementioned "More" dropdown tab hosting other tabs.

Does this make sense? Is there anything in Bootstrap 3 that is able to support such a thing?

Comment: Can you post the current markup for your tabs? Are there any bootstrap plugins you've already tried?

Comment: No, but I'm working on some jQuery code that is supposed to calculate the container width, and then decide what tab to move under the "More" tab. I hope I won't end up with bunch of spaghetti code but anyway, it seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @developer10 that would be AWESOME if you could show that when done. I posted a similar question last week to the boostrap people about leaving just 1 menu item outside of the drop-down and they said it wasn't supported, "only the brand and drop-down are shown, nothing else".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This demo on Bootply may help you:

### http://bootply.com/105764

It calculates the height of the tabs row. When the height exceed 50 pixels it moves the extra tabs into a dropdown. It will collapse/expand the tabs accordingly as the window is resized.

```
var autocollapse = function() {

  var tabs = $('#tabs');
  var tabsHeight = tabs.innerHeight();

  if (tabsHeight >= 50) {
    while(tabsHeight > 50) {

      var children = tabs.children('li:not(:last-child)');
      var count = children.size();
      $(children[count-1]).prependTo('#collapsed');

      tabsHeight = tabs.innerHeight();
    }
  }
  else {
    while(tabsHeight < 50 && (tabs.children('li').size()>0)) {

      var collapsed = $('#collapsed').children('li');
      var count = collapsed.size();
      $(collapsed[0]).insertBefore(tabs.children('li:last-child'));
      tabsHeight = tabs.innerHeight();
    }
    if (tabsHeight>50) { // double chk height again
        autocollapse();
    }
  }

};

$(document).ready(function() {

    autocollapse(); // when document first loads

    $(window).on('resize', autocollapse); // when window is resized

});
```